# Aрхитектура приложения

Tags: c++, qt, архитектура

Сразу прошу прощения за такой заголовок, я просто не знаю, как в двух словах описать проблему.

Ситуация следующая. Допустим, есть некий класс "рабочее место":

```
class Workplace{

};
```

и класс "работник", который знает, к какому рабочему месту он относится:

```
class Worker{
    Workplace *_workplace;
public:
    explicit Worker(Workplace *workplace):
        _workplace(workplace)
    {}
};
```

В процессе разработки оказалось, что было бы хорошо, если бы `Workplace` знал список всех, кто на нем работает. Наподобие того, как `QObject` знает список всех своих детей. Сделано это было примерно так:

```
class Worker;

class Workplace{
    std::vector<Worker*> _workers;
public:
    const std::vector<Worker*>& workers() const{
        return _workers;
    }
private:
    friend class Worker;
    void _add(Worker *worker){
        _workers.push_back(worker);
    }

    void _remove(Worker *worker){
        _workers.erase(std::remove(_workers.begin(), _workers.end(), worker), _workers.end());
    }
};

class Worker{
    Workplace *_workplace;
public:
    explicit Worker(Workplace *workplace)
    {
        setWorkplace(workplace);
    }
    void setWorkplace(Workplace *workplace){
        if(_workplace == workplace){
            return;
        }

        if(_workplace){
            _workplace->_remove(this);
        }

        if(workplace){
            workplace->_add(this);
        }

        _workplace = workplace;
    } 

    ~Worker(){
        setWorkplace(0);
    }
};
```

Если в двух словах: каждый раз, когда у работника меняется рабочее место, он сообщает старому, что он больше там не работает, и новому - что он там работает.

В таком небольшом примере все вроде бы работает как надо. Однако классов у меня гораздо больше, и код получился весьма запутанным. Может, кто-нибудь знает более элегантное решение этой проблемы? Ну или хотя бы её название, если оно есть.

**PS:** Есть еще класс, который содержит в себе весь этот зоопарк, назовем его `Company`:

```
class Company{
    std::vector<Worker*> _workers;
    std::vector<Workplace*> _workplaces;
//...
};
```

Теоретически он может выступать в роли посредника, однако я пока не придумал как это может мне помочь.

Comment: На мой взгляд, если стоит задача сделать графический редактор к базе данных (как выяснилось ниже в комментариях к ответу), то не нужно изобретать свои классы, а нужно использовать стандартные автоматически генерируемые DS. Свои классы имеет смысл делать к графической части, членами которых будут стандартные DS. Речь идет естественно о managed С++. – Александр Муксимов 7 минут назад

Answer (score 1):

> Может, кто-нибудь знает более элегантное решение этой проблемы? Ну или
>   хотя бы её название, если оно есть.

Задание на создание графа, или фактически стирание классов чтоб не писать много.
Пишешь один раз

```
class Container{
   Container * children;
public:
    explicit Container(Container* children):
       //и т.п.
    {}
};
```

потом все утилиты для контейнера.
пишешь один раз графическое представление Container вместе с его перетаксиванием.
Потом например

```
class Company{
std::vector<Container*> _workers;
std::vector<Container*> _workplaces;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, можно, например, держать одну большую таблицу с записями "работник/рабочее место" и при необходимости выполнять поиск в ней. Для небольшого количества записей - ну, там, тысячи - обычный вектор пар будет вполне адекватен. Если гораздо больше - можно подумать об ассоциативных контейнерах (типа, `multimap` может оказаться подходящим решением).

Если скорость критична - тогда надо жертвовать простотой и в каждом классе иметь соответствующие поля и при смене выполнять обновления - при большой запутанности, возможно, каскадные.

Задача скорее из БД :)

Comment: Так и есть, на самом деле эти структуры это представления таблиц из БД. И мне надо сделать графический редактор этой самой БД.

Comment: Ну так может воспользоваться чем-то типа SQLite? или непосредственно работать с этой базой?